# Cannot telnet to listening port and firewall rules

Tags: rhel, firewall, telnet

I am trying to telnet to a host on port 50000, which I verified that is listening to a DB2 instance (db2inst1).

```
 telnet [host] 50000

 telnet [ip_adress] 50000
```

But it gave the error: Connection timed out

I checked in the /etc/sysconfig/iptables file, and the firewall rules for port 50000 are properly set (they were saved and the iptables service was restarted):

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 50000 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 50000 -j ACCEPT
```

But still, I cannot telnet to this port. I disabled the service `iptables` and it allowed me to connect so that means there is something wrong with the firewall rules.

Answer (score 1):

The question your firewall rules not working, is that when a machine is connecting to your DB server, from the point of the DB server, it is indeed the destination port; however when a packet is leaving the DB server, from the point of view of the DB server, the DB service/listening port is the source port.

As such, correcting direct your rules, it should be:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 50000 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 50000 -j ACCEPT
```

Beware also of the localhost connections which are often needed by several daemons; you might need at the top of your rules:

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Depending on your security requirements, and your number of rules, I would have a look at the the [ESTABLISHED and RELATED directives](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=iptables+-A+INPUT+-m+state+--state+ESTABLISHED%2CRELATED+-j+ACCEPT). It would allow you to simplify your rules with stateful firewall aware rules.

> ESTABLISHED meaning that
>              the packet is associated with a connection which has seen packets in both directions, NEW  meaning
>              that  the packet has started a new connection, or otherwise associated with a connection which has
>              not seen packets in both directions, and RELATED  meaning  that  the  packet  is  starting  a  new
>              connection,  but  is  associated  with an existing connection, such as an FTP data transfer, or an
>              ICMP error.

Comment: Albeit out of topic, I would also advise reading Stevens "TCP/Illustrated, volume 1: The protocols" 2nd edition

Comment: The OUTPUT doesn't work with the flag -i, neither with lo. Why is that